# Gstreamer to android

Tags: android, stream, gstreamer

I'm trying to take a stream from a webcam and stream it to an android device. I use Gstreamer to grab the video and stream it out through a TCP server. That part of it works fine. The trouble I'm running into is that I need to make a custom app to receive the stream on the android and I can't get gst-android to compile (For reasons unknown to me, the adb is not a runnable, thus I can't set up the flingersinks.) Any suggestions? Is there something other and gst-android that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which android version are you targeting? As far as I know, the ndk version of gstreamer will still have problems to render video as no one contributed a working video sink. The surfaceflinger api is not available to ndk apps :/